# Universal function pointer for classes

Tags: c++

```
typedef void (*funcPtrType)(); // function pointer type
map<char,funcPtrType>eventGroups;

void addSharedEvent(char groupIndex,void (*receiverFunc)() ){
    if(groupIndex==0)
        return;

    eventGroups[groupIndex]=receiverFunc;

}
```

It works if adding inline functions but not if using non inlined class member functions like below...

```
void MainWin::uiValsUpdated()
{

}
void MainWin::test()
{
    //invalid
    wSync.addSharedEvent(4,&uiValsUpdated);
}
```

How to make universal pointer for accessing functions in various types of classes?
Alternatively could define class types also but still in universal manner like Qtˇs signals and slots for example.

Comment: Do you need to use only member function pointers for different classes, or do you need to support regular functions as well?

Comment: methods have silent additional argument which is represented by `this`, so in fact `MainWin::uiValsUpdated`  takes one argument.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> typedef void (*funcPtrType)(); // function pointer type
> ```

Avoid obfuscating pointer types like this.

> It works if adding inline functions but not if using non inlined class member

It has nothing to do inline vs non-inline, and everything to do with the fact that a function pointer cannot point to a non-static member function.

> How to make universal pointer for accessing functions in various types of classes?

A function pointer can point to functions except non-static member functions as long as the prototype matches. To call such function, no class instance is required. Example:

```
void free_function() {}
auto fun_ptr = &free_function;
fun_ptr();
```

A pointer to member function can point to non-static member functions of a particular class with matching prototype. In order to call such pointed function, there must be an instance of the class. Example:

```
struct foo {
    void member_function(){}
};
auto mem_fun_ptr = &foo::member_function;
foo f;
f.*mem_fun_ptr();
```

A function object can be used as a wrapper, and it can call any type of functions. If you want to call a member function, the needed instance can for example be stored as a member. A lambda is a shorthand for creating such function object. Example:

```
auto lambda_free = [] {
    free_function();
}

auto lambda_member = [f] {
    f.member_function();
}

lambda_free();
lambda_member();
```

Type erasure techniques can be used to hide the type of various function objects, since they can be called in the exactly same manner. Standard comes with a template for such purpose: `std::function`. Example:

```
std::function<void()> fun_wrapper;
fun_wrapper = lambda_free;
fun_wrapper = lambda_member;
fun_wrapper = fun_ptr;
//fun_wrapper = mem_fun_ptr; // nope; there is no instance of foo
```

Comment: `#include <functional>` is the only thing I'd add.

Comment: A mention of [std::invoke](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke) may make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Pointers to free functions are very different from those that point to member functions. Not only is the syntax different, member function pointers also need a `this` first argument - the instance of their class they are supposed to operate on. You cannot use the same `map` to store both, if you intend to deal with raw (member) function pointers.

One solution is some kind of type erasure; you can store `std::function` objects in your `map`:

```
map<char, std::function<void()>>eventGroups;

void addSharedEvent(char groupIndex, const std::function<void()>& callback){ ... }
```

You can construct the parameter by plain function pointers, and in case of member functions usage of `std::bind` or a lambda.

Comment: Full solution simplified - https://godbolt.org/z/o68hPK